# Find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}z^n$

---

My attempt:
$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ with $a_n = n!/n^n$. This gives
$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} |(n+1)\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}|$

We have $(n+1)\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = (n+1)(\frac{n}{n+1})^n \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} = (\frac{n}{n+1})^n = (\frac{1}{1+1/n})^n = e^{-1}$ for $n \to \infty$

The radius of convergence is $R = 1/L = e^1$

Is this correct ?